# Trying to undeform a curve for a caterpillar

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I am working on a caterpillar attempt using a sphere, array and curve deform modifiers on this program. But when I put on the curve, it doesn't look like as I wanted:

[image]

I was aiming for an undeformed look, but it can't seem to fix it. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, it should look like a pearl chain with equal-shaped spheres? Have you applied the scale?

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've just figured it out already. Thanks for your reply, I've found a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've just found out using `Instancing` > `Vertices` is a solution - looks like an alternative to the curve modifier.

[image]

[image]